# multiline text but fully heighty applied in transform rotate

Tags: html, css, transform

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TrCww/)

Demo html

```
<div class="controller">
<div><a href="#buttton-1">Special Offer</a></div>
</div>
```

Demo css

```
.controller{
    width: 55px;
    height: 216px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 0 19px 19px 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
.controller div{
    transform: rotate(90deg);

}
```

I could use `white-space: nowrap;` to `.controller div` it will increase the width of that controller and if I have long text this will have in one line. But I want this multiline but fully heighty as this.

[image]

Comment: anyway this time single line but without increasing the width of controller will be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,what about  [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/TrCww/3/)

```
.controller{  
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg);
width: 55px ! important;
height: 215px;
background: #000;
border-radius: 0 19px 19px 0;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
display: block;
float:left;
position:relative;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.controller div{
position: relative;
top: 90px;
left: -70px;
width: 190px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```